# How do I properly use Twig syntax in dynamic title/URL fields?

Tags: templating, control-panel

I have an idea to create urls for entries that can't be guessed, but are automated without any extra effort from the content creator/editors. The intention is for the URL not require any authentication, but not be "guessable" just because you have another similar URL.

My thought was to use the **Entry URL Format** field to automate this. I tried the following but it didn't work as expected:

```
documents/{ (id * 1234567) | number_format(0, null, '-') }
```

I assumed I could use any twig syntax here due to the description/label for the input field:

> What the entry URLs should look like. You can include tags that output entry properties, such as `{slug}` or `{postDate|date("Y")}`.

---

So, is it possible to do what I'm trying? What's the correct twig syntax here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After chatting with The Honorable Brad Bell I learned that the sample tags in the field's label are showing some shorthand references to a few variables. (The `{slug}` reference for example.)

All I needed to do was use the `object` object to fully utilize twig tags/filters/etc. Here are a few ways to achieve what I was aiming for:

```
{% set num = (object.id * 1234567) | number_format(0, null, '-') %}documents/{{ num }}
```

or slightly more concise code:

```
documents/{{ (object.id * 1234567) | number_format(0, null, '-') }}
```

Also, thanks to carlsc for sharing the documentation on this feature. Reference: https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles.

Happy Dynamic Titling and URLing.

Comment: It's documented in the "Sections and Entries" section of the Craft docs. https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries#dynamic-entry-titles

Comment: @carlcs Thanks so much for the link! I couldn't find it when I went hunting. :)