# Craft Routing / Variables with Differing URI

Tags: routing

I have a project which I'm working on which is going to need something similar to the following URL Structure :

`site.com/dfe45c4f/news_title`, `site.com/gyb66dx/news_title` or `site.com/76vvg3s/news_title`

The First URI Segment is the 'Partner Reference' - a hash value for every partner we work with, the second is a simple entry url title. Every page will show the same data, but each page will be 'branded' differently based on the Partner Reference.

What I need to do is to query a Craft channel a set a variety of variables (styling/logo/branding etc) for the page based on the partner reference.

How would I set routing to look up the first Segment URI to look at the partner section and return all the field information as variables?

Thanks

Comment: Ugghhh, can't you do anything about that URL structure? Even something like `site.com/p/dfe45c4f/news_title` would allow you to easily route it to a template called "p.html" and then perform your logic in there.

Comment: Yes, I _could_... would that be a preferred way of doing it then? Or just easier?

Comment: see my answer which should hopefully help explain

Comment: Rather than considering routing, try an **Entry URL Format** of something like `{{ object.partnerReference }}/{{ slug }}` that just points to a template that contains the logic to apply the correct branding changes. Similar example: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/13622/how-do-i-properly-use-twig-syntax-in-dynamic-title-url-fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Settings → Routes, and create a route like this:

[image]

Then create that `partners/_partner_news_entry.html` template. (You can change the location/name of the template if you want; just make sure it matches the “Load this template” setting within your route.)

In that template, you can get the Partner Reference and the entry slug like this:

```
{% set partnerRef = matches[1] %}
{% set entrySlug = matches[2] %}
```

I’m not sure how you have it set up, but assuming you have a “Partners” channel with a “Partner Reference” custom field, which stores all of the styling/logo/branding info you need, you can get those relevant entries like this:

```
{% set partnerEntry = craft.entries({
    section: 'partners',
    partnerReference: partnerRef
}).first() %}
```

Make sure it’s a valid Partner Reference like this:

```
{% if not partnerEntry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

Do the same stuff for the News entry:

```
{% set newsEntry = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    slug: entrySlug
}).first() %}

{% if not newsEntry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}
```

If there’s an Entries field that actually ties the News entries to a specific partner and you want to ensure that you’re not viewing a News entry that should have only been associated with someone else, you can tweak that like this:

```
{% set newsEntry = craft.entries({
    section: 'news',
    slug: entrySlug,
    relatedTo: {targetElement: partnerEntry},
}).first() %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a solid way of setting up routing to handle all of the possible use cases for your URL structure as it is now.

You could set up a dynamic route to look for URI's that are of the form `slug/slug` and then route them to a custom template where you can then deal with the logic. But this route is very ambiguous and could easily catch false positives.

In my opinion a better way would be to use an extra URI segment in your dynamic route, for example `partner/slug/slug` or `p/slug/slug` for brevity. Then you can be sure that this will load the custom template only in the correct use cases.

Note that the `slug` in the dynamic route above does not necessarily represent a slug, but any string of characters, except for a forward slash. So you can then do whatever you need to in your custom template.

Answer (score 1):

**CRAFT CMS 3**

I had a similar issue, and the way I solved it in Craft CMS 3 was through routes, similar to the answer from Brandon Kelly.

I have the entries `location`, `category` and `subcategory`. These last two without URI (they are just entries without URL).

But I want to display a template when visiting the routes:

// Route for menu, categories and subcategories e.g. paris/menu/after-5pm/salads:

*location*/menu/*category/subcategory*

// Route for menu and categories e.g. paris/menu/after-5pm:

*location*/menu/category*

So what I did in my config/routes.php was:

```
<?php

return [

    // Route for menu, categories and subcategories e.g. paris/menu/after-5pm/salads
    '<location>/menu/<category>/<subcategory>' => ['template' => 'locations/_menu-entry'],

    // Route for menu and categories e.g. paris/menu/after-5pm
    '<location>/menu/<category>' => ['template' => 'locations/_menu-entry'],

];
```

and in my locations/_menu-entry.twig file was:

```
{% set locationEntry = craft.entries.section('store').slug(location).one()  %}
{% set categoryEntry = craft.entries.section('menuCategory').slug(category).one()  %}
{% set subcategoryEntry = subcategory is defined ? craft.entries.section('menuSubcategories').slug(subcategory).one() : null %}

{% if not locationEntry or not categoryEntry %}
    {% exit 404 %}
{% endif %}

... manipulate entries as needed...
```

Hope this helps!